# Flutter GridView not showing equally spaced items

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-desktop

This is my code and it's supposed to create a uniform pattern:

```
GridView.builder(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount 30),
          itemCount: 30 * 30,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
            );
          },
    ),
```

But it's an irregular pattern of lines and dots. I'm expecting uniform e.g. equidistant lines according to padding or equidistant dots according to the radius of `container`. Now all spacing values are zero there shouldn't be any line, it seems there's some other controlling factor.

I'm running this code on Desktop.

[image]